# Unable to create match in Game Center game

Tags: ios, game-center

I have got some complains from a few number of my users, that when they try to create a game an UIAlertViewController pops up saying:

> Unable to create match. Please try again later.

This has never happened to me, or lets say 90% of my other users. What is the reason some of my users face this problem?

This is my code:

```
func findMatchWithMinPlayers(minPlayers: Int, maxPlayers: Int, viewController: UIViewController?) {
    if !gameCenterAvailable {
        return
    }
    self.presentingViewController = viewController!
    let request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.minPlayers = 2
    request.maxPlayers = 2
    let mmvc = GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
    mmvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self
    mmvc.showExistingMatches = true
    presentingViewController.presentViewController(mmvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Without code, nobody can help you.

Comment: I don´t think it a code issue... A user who faced this problem got it working 1 hour later.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please help other people to help you by following these guidelines when asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If the issue is nothing to do with code then no-one on this website can help you as this is a website for programming issues.

Comment: Well it is a programming issue... I have read some people saying the player has to turn on his invites in order to create a match, but some of my users has invites on, and still isn´t able to create a match.

Comment: Then edit your question to include the relevant MCVE code along with what debugging information you can provide. You can also delete your comment about it not being about code.

Comment: Show your code where you authenticate the local player, please. Also, have the users reported an error domain and error number?

Comment: I'm getting the same error (using Unity and IOSNative) with code that was working earlier. @AppleSupport on Twitter acknowledge they have had reports of the error (https://twitter.com/nick_thompson/status/738498821714550784). This evening Apple has had a lot of issues with their cloud services; I suspect this is a GameCenter issue, not a code one (as such).